# Handling low quality work from a senior

Tags: software-industry, team, manager

> This is a question regarding the software industry, but would apply equally to any industry in which teams contribute work to a final product.

How do I handle having to completely rework the work of my team leader?

Recently, I was undertaking some pair programming at work with a peer (actually my senior developer, but closer to a peer than a senior) in which we decided that the work done by our team leader in the previous weeks would need to be re-done. Briefly: there were absolutely no tests and the methodologies and the approach taken was not maintainable in the long run.

As it happens, he has been on holiday in this time; though I believe we'd have made the same decision were he in the office. How best can I\we handle telling him what we've done? I can defend the technical decisions we made, but I'm not confident that he'll accept the reasons for the genuine technical reasons they are (i.e. the actions taken were not intended as any kind of personal attack or reflection).

---

**Update** to answer questions in comments.

1. What triggered the code changes? A bug report from QA (the feature has yet to reach production)
2. Has anybody else has reviewed his code? No. There is a code review tool and process in place, but it's rarely used and followed.

Comment: 1.  What incident was it that triggered your review of the code? For example, something broke down and in the process of investigating why, you checked the code and you collected a whole sackful of worms. 2. From your narrative, it looks like your team leader's coding was slapdash affair. Has anybody besides the two of you reviewed his code? The more senior people you have by your side, the less likely he'll make a fight out of it.

Comment: I've added answers to the comments in the question

Comment: Tests can be written.  The important thing here is that the architecture chosen was not good enough.  This should have been caught before any code was written.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Code reviews are the answer.  I assume if you're doing paired programming, there is a code review methodology in place as well.

Where I'm currently working, all code gets reviewed before it can be merged into the master codebase.  This is the place where issues can be raised and discussed with the developer in a non-confrontational manner.

Raise your issues during this process with your coworker and offer what you think is the better way.  If it's a matter of just following coding standards (not a matter of which way is better--just which way is "accepted"), explain that standards are important for ease of maintenance.

If you're not doing code reviews, definitely institute them.

Answer (score 9):

> How best can I\we handle telling him what we've done?

Ideally, by not telling him what you've done, but by asking "Wouldn't X be better?" beforehand. Going behind someone's back (senior or not) and undoing their work is on the border of unprofessional. It gives the impression that you think they are incompetent, and that they're so bad (either as a person or professionally) that you don't even want to work with them to make it better.

For software engineers, I would focus on the problem the code is solving. Pretty much all software engineers love to solve problems. By focusing on what the code is trying to solve, you're focusing on *that* problem, not the problem you have with their code. You're being a good team player and presenting a better solution for that problem. Then you can debate the relative merits versus the problem rather than criticizing their code.

Comment: "think they are incompetent and that they're so bad .. that you don't even want to work with them". This is what I feared he would think. I would've liked to try work with him on this, but it wasn't an option at the time. The work is now done and in the codebase. Is it still possible to start a conversation purely about the problem?

Comment: @AndyBursh - it's probably better than just letting him find out about it himself.

Comment: @Chris, Telastyn Would you agree that then that allowing him to find out for himself, and being prepared to participate in a code review, is the best approach?

Comment: @AndyBursh: No, it's better to address it directly, but as Telastyn said you should talk about the code not about the person. Try to phrase it like you made his good work even better and ask if he agrees or has more suggestions.

Comment: @Chris That sounds like a good, positive solution. Thanks!

Comment: @AndyBursh - you should definitely **not** just leave the code there. You should "suggest a better solution", which would be easier to do _before_ burning down their hard work.

Comment: +1 : _Going behind someone's back (senior or not) and undoing their work is on the border of unprofessional_

Answer (score 3):

There are many paths, the best one depends on the environment.

Given you have already done the deed, the best way to present it is "Jane and I were using your code, and as we used it we came up with some ideas to improve it. Can we review these with you (e.g., in a code review) and see what you think?" Now the senior is in the authority role, if not the actual expert, and the discussion can be about the technical changes. Hopefully you can have that discussion in a healthy engineering way, and the senior can be pleasantly enlightened.

If there's likely to be bad karma -- e.g., your senior has a history of writing bad code and being defensive about it, and isn't there when you need to decide what to do -- then you have to choose the lesser of evils up front: make the changes silently; don't make the changes at all; or make the changes to allow you to go forward, then trash (and rebaseline) them before merging into the visible code base. Each of these has obvious consequences, but you will be in the best position to guess what they are.

Comment: At the the time of writing, the changes have been made silently and pushed in to the main branch; as a matter of circumstance (his not being present) rather than choice. Is it still possible at this point to start a conversation in a positive manner?

Comment: Absolutely, if the relationship overall is a reasonably good one. "Hey boss, we made some changes to some of your code to help us go forward while you were gone. We checked them, but can we get you to review them with us to see if we've created issues?" If the boss likes going forward this should come across OK.

But if the boss is defensive/difficult, you've lost him/her at "made changes to your code", and if the boss is a bad coder you still have a problem getting to agreement on the changes. That's a different question.